# Efficient way to compare vectorial direction?

Tags: mathematics, vector, axis, orientation

I have a bunch of random vectors representing a direction and four other vectors that we can distinguish with their pyramidal arrows at their extremity, they represent a boundary

what i'd like to do is figure out which vectors are within the given boundaries,
how can I do that?
How can I compare them to filter them properly so the only one selected are vectors within the four boundary direction

I have as info:
directional vector / XYZ Euler angle

[image]
[image]

Comment: This looks similar to a frustum culling check. There we define a plane for each side of the camera's view pyramid, and use dot products to check whether a vector is on the "inside" side of each plane. Have you looked at these techniques for some inspirations?

Comment: That's exactly what i was trying to do! i'll check asap, if you have some article to share let me knpw

Comment: @DB3D since there is no other answer for now, if you haven't found anything yet, this is a good place regarding frustum techniques in general (not only culling/clipping): http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html although it's more about the projection of objects from inside the pyramid to a plane close to the pyramid tip, but you might get the gist